# Zerorpc asynchronous calls

Tags: python, asynchronous, zeromq, zerorpc

### Server

Suppose I have the following zerorpc server

```py
#server side
import zerorpc

class API():

    def long_running_task(self):
        print('1 - started long_running_task')
        #for instance a long running SQL query
        zerorpc.gevent.sleep(10)
        print('2 - finished long_running_task')

    def other_task(self):
        print('1 - started other_task')
        pass
        print('2 - finished other_task')

s = zerorpc.Server(API())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4444")
zerorpc.gevent.spawn(s.run)
while True:
    zerorpc.gevent.sleep(10)
```

### Client

and a client app which sends several requests simultanously

```py
import zerorpc

client = zerorpc.Client()
client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4444")

client.long_running_task(async_=True)
client.other_task(async_=True)

client.close()
```

The problem is that while the long_running_task is being executed the other_task doesn't start running.

The desired output is:

```
1 - started long_running_task
1 - started other_task
2 - finished other_task
2 - finished long_running_task
```

instead of

```
1 - started long_running_task
2 - finished long_running_task
1 - started other_task
2 - finished other_task
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here

1. `async_` should be `async`. This ensures client method returns immediately
2. ZeroRPC works with gevent. So you need to start the server with `gevent.spawn(s.run)`. Also to keep your main greenlet running.

```
zerorpc.gevent.spawn(s.run)
while True:
     zerorpc.gevent.sleep(10)
```

3. above 2 is not enough. In the `API()` methods you need to be co-operative too.  Instead of `time.sleep()` use `gevent.sleep()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I edited the question based on point 2 and 3. To point 1: the problem is that if I use async keyword I get a syntax error (I have python 3.7). https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32816 . After making the changes the script still doesn't run as intended..

Comment: `async=True` can be written as `**{"async": True}`

Comment: I thought that async was replaced by async_ in the library, my bad.. Thanks for the help!